# Permutations of n distinct objects in r groups, given that some objects may not be able to go into some groups?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For example, let's say there are groups A, B and C and objects 1, 2 and 3.

Objects 1 and 2 can go in groups A, B and C, but object 3 is only allowed in groups A and B. How many different ways can the objects be placed in the groups (order within groups matters [ie. A: 1, 2; B: 3; C: NULL is distinct from A: 2, 1; B: 3; C: NULL])?

Is there some sort of formula that can be applied to any situation given n, r and knowing which objects are permitted in each group?

Comment: Doesn't seem likely if you only know how many objects can go in each group, and not _which_ ones. Example: A allows 123, B 1, C 1. There's only 3 combinations without considering order. But if A allows 123, B 1, C 2 then there's 4 different combinations.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question for clarity, but it will actually be possible to determine exactly which objects can fit in which groups. How does this change things? Thanks for your help!

Comment: My suspicion is that this is closely related to this previous Question, [Maximum unique pairings between two lists of repeated items](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156201/maximum-unique-pairings-between-two-lists-of-repeated-items).  If nothing else it might help you to clarify your formulation of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see Emisor just gave a much simpler example in a comment; I'll leave this up anyway...

---

No, there isn't because the answer isn't determined by that information. For instance, if there are four groups and four objects and each group accepts two objects, then we could have groups $A$ and $B$ accepting objects $1$ and $2$ and groups $C$ and $D$ accepting objects $3$ and $4$, with $6^2=36$ possibilities, or group $A$ accepting objects $1$ and $2$, group $B$ accepting objects $2$ and $3$, group $C$ accepting objects $3$ and $4$ and group $D$ accepting objects $4$ and $1$, with $26$ possibilities.

Comment: Hi, joriki. Thanks, that totally makes sense, but I actually did determine a way to figure out exactly which objects can fit into which groups (just edited my question to reflect that). Would there be a way to do so now?

Comment: @polarbearfood: I doubt it. Of course you can count the possibilities by computer, but I don't see a way of doing it in closed form. But you never know...